# How to style a radio button with border and color

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to give a different color of my radio button as well the border color?

I tried using this code but it does not seem to work perfectly.

```css
li.payment_method_bacs input[type='radio']:checked:before {
    background: black !important;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 19px;
    left: 3px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

li.payment_method_bacs input[type='radio']:checked:before {
    background: black !important;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 19px;
    left: 3px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input id="payment_method_bacs" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" data-order_button_text="" checked="checked">
```

Comment: you can go through this link hope it might be helpful "http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=custom-radio-buttons" if use bootstrap theme it could be far easy since it provides this feature already.As it avoids writing of too much of code for such small requirement hence I prefer bootstrap theme in place of writing code for the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying `:after and :before` on the **input element** which is **invalid with css**. So you **need to wrap** other things **like a div** to achieve this. The div will use the **checked value** of radio and with `:after and :before` element will do the thing as needed. I am using 2 approaches.

> **Approach 1: using div as faux element:**

```css
li {
  list-style: none; display:inline-block; margin-right:20px;
}

.radioBox {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radioBox>div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.radioBox>input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.radioBox > input:checked + div:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    font-size: 0;
    display: block;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="payment_method_bacs">
    <div class="radioBox "><input id="payment_method_bacs" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" data-order_button_text="" >
      <div></div>
    </div>

  </li>
  
  <li>
<div class="radioBox ">
  <input id="payment_method_bacs1" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" data-order_button_text="" checked="checked" >
    <div></div>

</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

> **Approach 2 : Using label as faux element.**

```css
ul,li{list-style:none; display:inline-block;}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
 
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
 
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
 border:1px solid #000;
 border-radius:50%;
}
.radio label:before {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: #000;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<div class="radio">
  <input id="payment_method_bacs" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" data-order_button_text="" checked="checked">
  <label for="payment_method_bacs">Visa</label>

</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="radio">
  <input id="payment_method_bacs1" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" data-order_button_text="" >
  <label for="payment_method_bacs1">Paypal</label>

</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Approach two suited better for me. Appreciate the support

Answer (score 0):

add html in input and lable tag input will be hide if check box will check than you can add style anything in lable

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}


input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 0 solid #333;
  content: "";
  font-size: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="input-lif in-lidt">
  <input class="contact_radio" id="rbsrt1" name="contact" value="individual" checked="checked" type="radio">
  <label for="rbsrt1"> Individual </label>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing the appearance of form inputs it's a little bit tricky, as each browser renders them in a different manner.

To ensure you get the same result for different browsers, you might consider using an image (inline, or as a background image for the element containing the input) or an element, as your input display.

```
  <label id="myLabel" for="payment_method_bacs">
    <input id="payment_method_bacs" 
      type="radio" 
      class="input-radio" 
      name="payment_method" 
      value="bacs" 
      data-order_button_text="" 
      checked="checked">
  </label>

  #myLabel{
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: white;
      -moz-border-radius: 50px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      border:2px solid #ccc;
      display:inline-block;
  }

  #myLabel input{
      display:none;
  }
```

Fiddle provided here: https://jsfiddle.net/omfv8qhj/

Comment: With the background image then I will not be able to give color to the actual button

Comment: You can use an element, which you can customize as you want, with background, border etc